# Agular Store effects not waiting for selectors data

Tags: angular, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects, ngrx-selectors

Am working on an **Angula**r project using **NgRx store**. All the back end responses are saved in the store.

This is my **effects.ts**

```
loadData$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType('[Data] Load Data'),
      concatMap((action: any) => of(action).pipe(
        withLatestFrom(this.store$.pipe(select(selectorData)))
        
      )),
      switchMap(([, request]: any) => this.Service.getDataApi(
          request.data1.iid,
          request.data2.iid2
        )
        .pipe(
          map((data: Data[]) => ({
              type: '[Data] Load Success',
              payload:  { data },
            }
          )),
          catchError((error: any) => of({
              type: '[Datae]] Load Failure',
              payload:  { error },
            }
          ))
        ))
    )
  );
```

How can i wait for **selectorData** data?
Is there any specific method for that?
Current implementation **idd** and **iid2** are empty.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit 1**
I have made below changes

```
concatMap((action: any) => of(action).pipe(
        withLatestFrom(this.store$.pipe(select(selectorData),skipWhile(iid => !iid),
        skipWhile(iid2 => !iid2),
        mapTo(true))
        )
```

Above changes it will not call with the API.how can i call if the data is available

**Edit 2**

```
filter(([, {configData}]: any) => configData.iid &&
      configData.iid)
```

I have tried filter as well. First time  **configData.iid** is undefined.how can we solve this issue

It throwing undefined error

**Edit 3**
I have tried **combineLatestWith**.it doesn't wait for `this.store$.pipe(select(selectorData))`

Any other solution for waiting data?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `combineLatest` to wait for multiple actions or source observables.

```
loadData $ = createEffect(() => {
    return combineLatest(
      this.actions$.pipe(
          ofType('[Data] Load Data')
      ),
      this.store$.pipe(
          select(selectorData),
          filter(iid => !!iid) // Filters untruthy values
      )
    ).pipe(
      // Wont come here until both observables have emitted
      ...
    )
```

Comment: can u please update ur answer with my code. Am new in angular